# How to make the amount to pay to be the actual price not a static value when using Stripe?

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe payment in Flutter and When setting my functions the app pays the static (hardcoded ) value, for example, $50. But once I want it to get the actual price on the cart it is not processing.
Here is my makePayment() function:

```
  Future<void> makePayment() async {
try {
 String  amount = bookingModel.totalfare.toString();

  paymentIntentData =
  await createPaymentIntent(amount, 'USD'); //json.decode(response.body);

  await Stripe.Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
      paymentSheetParameters: Stripe.SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
          paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentIntentData['client_secret'],
          applePay: true,
          googlePay: true,
          testEnv: true,
          style: ThemeMode.dark,
        //  merchantCountryCode: 'US',
          merchantDisplayName: 'My Company')).then((value){
         });

    displayPaymentSheet();
      } catch (e, s) {
     print('exception:$e$s');
    }
  }
```

And From here I also have the payment sheet displayed:

```
displayPaymentSheet() async {

try {
   await Stripe.Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet(
      parameters: Stripe.PresentPaymentSheetParameters(
        clientSecret: paymentIntentData['client_secret'],
        confirmPayment: true,
      )).then((newValue){
     print('payment intent'+paymentIntentData['id'].toString());
    print('payment intent'+paymentIntentData['client_secret'].toString());
    print('payment intent'+paymentIntentData['amount'].toString());
    print('payment intent'+paymentIntentData.toString());
    //orderPlaceApi(paymentIntentData!['id'].toString());
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Paid 
   successfully")));

    paymentIntentData = null;

  }).onError((error, stackTrace){
    print('Exception/DISPLAYPAYMENTSHEET==> $error $stackTrace');
  });


} on Stripe.StripeException catch (e) {
  print('Exception/DISPLAYPAYMENTSHEET==> $e');
  showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
        content: Text("Cancelled "),
      ));
} catch (e) {
  print('$e');
 }
}
```

And finally the payment Intent. This is done on the frontend for now but I will use cloud functions when deploying.

```
  createPaymentIntent(String amount, String currency) async {

try {
  Map<String, dynamic> body = {
    'amount':  calculateAmount(amount),
    'currency': currency,
    'payment_method_types[]': 'card'
  };
  print(body);
  var response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents'),
      body: body,
      headers: {
        'Authorization':
        'Bearer sk_test_my_Key',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      });
  print('Create Intent reponse ===> ${response.body.toString()}');
  return jsonDecode(response.body);
} catch (err) {
  print('err charging user: ${err.toString()}');
   }
 }
calculateAmount(String amount) {
  final a = (int.parse('50'))* 100 ;
  return a.toString();
 }
```

My main issue is to have the amount to be defined as  amount = bookingModel.totalfare.toString() and pass it in my function but this doesnt work at all.

Your assistance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: For creating the Payment Intent, I know you will use cloud function, but please keep in mind that you shouldn't even do this for testing. The Secret key should never been exposed in client code or you would need to re-roll it.

Comment: Thanks @orakaro I will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You have things set up, change the last function to this:

```
String calculateAmount() {
  return ((int.tryParse(amount)?? 0 ) * 100).toString() ;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks @Huthaifa I tried that but still not working